# how could flatten the nested array of addToSet

Tags: mongodb

I have a post doc exist an array field -- topics e.g.

```
"topics":['topic 1','topic 2']
```

Now I want to group by author and get all topics of the author's posts, I used `addToSet` to implement it

```
{$group: {"_id":"$screen_name",post_count:{$sum:1}, "topics":{$addToSet:"$topics"} } }
```

and the result is like this

```
"topics" : [ [ "topic 1","topic 2" ], [ "topic 3" ], [ "topic 4" ] ]
```

I want to know how could let it to return below output

```
"topics" : ["topic 1" ,"topic 2" , "topic 3","topic 4" ]
```

that is flatted the first output.

Comment: What is your mongod version?

Comment: the version is 3.2

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to unwind twice and regroup :

```
[
{$group: {"_id":"$screen_name",post_count:{$sum:1}, "topics":{$addToSet:"$topics"} } },
{$unwind: "$topics"},
{$unwind: "$topics"},
{$group : {
    _id : "$_id",
    post_count : {$first: "$post_count"},
    topics : {$addToSet : "$topics"}
    }}
]
```

Unwind returns a distinct document for each element in your array, so unwinding twice would allow you to flatten the whole array of arrays.

Comment: some cumbersome and sum post_count in last group cause wrong post_count, e.g. Author A only have one post but with topics:[t1,t2,t3] in your manner the post_count would be 3